# Material Table React Editable columns Date Picker Warnings

Tags: reactjs, datatable, material-ui

I am working on material-table .

I need to add couple of columns to my **data table**.I need to add a **date time picker** to one of the columns(editable).The other column should not be editable. So I defined my columns as shown below.

```
const columns1 = [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name', type: 'string', editable: 'never' },
    { title: 'Birth Date', field: 'birthDate', type: 'datetime' }
];
```

I referred the code from https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/editable.

Modified data table as shown below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";


const columns1 = [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name', type: 'string', editable: 'never' },
    { title: 'Birth Date', field: 'birthDate', type: 'datetime' }
];
const data1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'user1', birthDate: '2020-08-01 10:08:00' },
{ id: 2, name: 'user2', birthDate: '2020-09-01 06:24:00' }];

class Chart4 extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: data1
        }
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>

                <MaterialTable
                    title="Simple Material Table"
                    columns={columns1}
                    data={data1}
                    cellEditable={{
                        onCellEditApproved: (newValue, oldValue, rowData, columnDef) => {
                            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                                let date = new Date(newValue);

                                let monthNumber = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                let day = date.getDate();
                                let hour = date.getHours();
                                let minutes = date.getMinutes();
                                let seconds = date.getSeconds();

                                month = month < 10 ? `0${month}` : month;
                                day = day < 10 ? `0${day}` : day;
                                hour = hour < 10 ? `0${hour}` : hour;
                                minutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes;
                                seconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : seconds;

                                var month = new Array();
                                month[0] = "JAN";
                                month[1] = "FEB";
                                month[2] = "MAR";
                                month[3] = "APR";
                                month[4] = "MAY";
                                month[5] = "JUN";
                                month[6] = "JUL";
                                month[7] = "AUG";
                                month[8] = "SEP";
                                month[9] = "OCT";
                                month[10] = "NOV";
                                month[11] = "DEC";

                                let monthIntext = month[monthNumber - 1];

                                let formattedDate = day + "-" + monthIntext + "-" + date.getFullYear() + " " + hour + ":" + minutes;
                                let dataTemp = [...this.state.data];
                                dataTemp.forEach(userInfo => {
                                    if (userInfo.id === rowData.id) {
                                        userInfo[columnDef.field] = formattedDate;
                                    }
                                })
                                setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
                            });
                        }
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Chart4;
```

This seems to work , But I am getting couple of warnings as shown below.

```
    index.js:1 Warning: React does not recognize the `cellEditable` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `celleditable` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.
        in td (created by ForwardRef(TableCell))
        in ForwardRef(TableCell) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)) (created by MTableCell)
        in MTableCell (created by MTableBodyRow)
        in tr (created by ForwardRef(TableRow))
        in ForwardRef(TableRow) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)) (created by MTableBodyRow)
        in MTableBodyRow (created by MTableBody)
        in tbody (created by ForwardRef(TableBody))
        in ForwardRef(TableBody) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)) (created by MTableBody)
        in MTableBody (created by Droppable)
        in table (created by ForwardRef(Table))
        in ForwardRef(Table) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)) (created by Droppable)
        in div (created by Droppable)
        in div (created by Droppable)
        in div (created by Droppable)
        in Droppable (created by ConnectFunction)
        in ConnectFunction
        in ConnectFunction (created by MaterialTable)
        in div
        in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
        in WithStyles(Component) (created by MaterialTable)
        in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
        in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
        in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Container)
        in Container (created by MaterialTable)
        in Provider (created by App)
        in App (created by ErrorBoundary)
        in ErrorBoundary (created by DragDropContext)
        in DragDropContext (created by MaterialTable)
        in MaterialTable
        in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
        in WithStyles(Component) (at Chart4.js:24)
        in div (at Chart4.js:22)
        in Chart4 (at App.js:9)
        in div (at App.js:8)
        in App (at src/index.js:9)
        in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)

index.js:1 Warning: Unknown event handler property `onCellEditStarted`. It will be ignored.
    in td (created by ForwardRef(TableCell))
    in ForwardRef(TableCell) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableCell)) (created by MTableCell)
    in MTableCell (created by MTableBodyRow)
    in tr (created by ForwardRef(TableRow))
    in ForwardRef(TableRow) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)) (created by MTableBodyRow)
    in MTableBodyRow (created by MTableBody)
    in tbody (created by ForwardRef(TableBody))
    in ForwardRef(TableBody) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)) (created by MTableBody)
    in MTableBody (created by Droppable)
    in table (created by ForwardRef(Table))
    in ForwardRef(Table) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)) (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in Droppable (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction
    in ConnectFunction (created by MaterialTable)
    in div
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (created by MaterialTable)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Container)
    in Container (created by MaterialTable)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by ErrorBoundary)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by DragDropContext)
    in DragDropContext (created by MaterialTable)
    in MaterialTable
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (at Chart4.js:24)
    in div (at Chart4.js:22)
    in Chart4 (at App.js:9)
    in div (at App.js:8)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:88
error @ react-dom.development.js:60
validateProperty$1 @ react-dom.development.js:5484
warnUnknownProperties @ react-dom.development.js:5595
validateProperties$2 @ react-dom.development.js:5619
validatePropertiesInDevelopment @ react-dom.development.js:5662
setInitialProperties @ react-dom.development.js:5941
finalizeInitialChildren @ react-dom.development.js:7499
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:18978
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22192
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:22165
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:22130
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:21756
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:21188
updateContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24373
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:24758
unbatchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:21903
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:24757
render @ react-dom.development.js:24840
./src/index.js @ index.js:7
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:784
fn @ bootstrap:150
1 @ serviceWorker.js:141
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:784
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1 Warning: Unknown event handler property `onCellEditFinished`. It will be ignored.
    in tr (created by ForwardRef(TableRow))
    in ForwardRef(TableRow) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableRow)) (created by MTableBodyRow)
    in MTableBodyRow (created by MTableBody)
    in tbody (created by ForwardRef(TableBody))
    in ForwardRef(TableBody) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TableBody)) (created by MTableBody)
    in MTableBody (created by Droppable)
    in table (created by ForwardRef(Table))
    in ForwardRef(Table) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Table)) (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in div (created by Droppable)
    in Droppable (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction
    in ConnectFunction (created by MaterialTable)
    in div
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (created by MaterialTable)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by Container)
    in Container (created by MaterialTable)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App (created by ErrorBoundary)
    in ErrorBoundary (created by DragDropContext)
    in DragDropContext (created by MaterialTable)
    in MaterialTable
    in Unknown (created by WithStyles(Component))
    in WithStyles(Component) (at Chart4.js:24)
    in div (at Chart4.js:22)
    in Chart4 (at App.js:9)
    in div (at App.js:8)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

Can someone tell me what needs to be done to fix these warnings?
Also if any improvements can be done to onCellEditApproved? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using `react-table` in my application, This issue is related to the current version of the library, no issue in your code for this matter. There is a thread with this ongoing problem being discussed [right here](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/2244) in the library's GitHub. If you are concerned with the production environment, this will not be shown there.